# Changing window position with javascript to a specific element?

Tags: javascript, window

Say I've got a big list of elements which are displayed vertically.

How can you change the window position so that a specified element in the list is shown at the top of the page with javascript?

Does this method work for major browsers (ie 6+, firefox, safari, chrome)?

Thanks

Comment: Is this "list of elements" a true list (as in a list box) or is it a long list of something like div elements?

Comment: yes it is an actual <ul> with <li> elements

Answer (score 2):

[`window.scrollTo(xPosition, yPosition)`](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/ecmascript/quickref/win_scrollto.html)

> This method scrolls the contents of a window, the specified co-ordinate becoming the top left corner of the viewable area. Both parameters are integers and they represent the x and y co-ordinates in pixels. This method is only useful where there are areas of the document not viewable within the current viewable area of the window and the visible property of the window's scrollbar must be set to true (enabled).

Combine that with [code to find an element's position](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) et voilà!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jQuery here, but you could easily adapt the logic to any other JS library or even POJ:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4 -- Should move to the top in 5 seconds</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>

function changeList(){
    $('li:nth-child(4)').prependTo('ul');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var t = setTimeout('changeList()',5000);
});
```

[Demo](http://jquery.nodnod.net/cases/588/run) (make sure to view source)

Note: Updated the code & demo to not use an ID selector and to use setTimeout(), per his request in a comment.

Comment: is it possible to do this without the use of '#'? i have a special purpose for # so it can't be replaced. also i'd like to be able to move to the specified list element at some arbitrary time after window load

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `scrollIntoView` function. When you have a reference  (say in var `el`) to the element you want to view simply call `el.scrollIntoView (true)` to put that element at the top of the window or el.scrollIntoView (false) to put it at the bottom of the window.
Unfortunately there is no (easy) mean so centering the element :-(